# LINQ to Entitiesで「各カラムの最大値」を求める良い方法を教えてください

Tags: c#, linq

あるテーブルの各カラムの最大値を1つのクエリで取り出したいです。
SQLで書けば、下記のようになると思います。

```
select max(column1),max(column2),max(column3) from table1;
```

これをLINQを使って下記のように実現しましたが、例1では複数のクエリが発行されてしまいますし、例2では「GroupBy句でIDに0を掛けて1つのグループにする」ことで疑似的に実現しているため、うまくないように思えます。
LINQで無理やりではない（より良い）実現方法を教えていただけるでしょうか？

例1.

```
var column1 = db.table1.Max(a => a.column1);
var column2 = db.table1.Max(a => a.column2);
var column3 = db.table1.Max(a => a.column3);
```

例2.

```
db.table1.GroupBy(a => a.Id * 0).Select(a => new {
  column1 = a.Max(b => b.column1),
  column2 = a.Max(b => b.column2),
  column3 = a.Max(b => b.column3),
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

フレームワーク：.Net Framework 4.6.1、Entity Framework 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select max(column1),max(column2),max(column3) from table1;

これは全てのRDBで使える構文じゃないので、Entity Framework では難しいのじゃないでしょうか？
Entity Framework はそもそも遅いので妥協が必要です。
記載のやり方は最適解かはともかく、適解ではあると思います。
ただ、GroupBy(a => a.Id * 0) は GroupBy(a => 0) のほうが単一グループだと解り易いのでは？

Comment: "これは全てのRDBで使える構文じゃない" という認識がありませんでした。確かに、すべての構文に無いのであれば、Entity Frameworkでは吸収できないと理解しました。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> select max(column1),max(column2),max(column3) from table1;
> ```

はSQL標準に従っているので大抵のRDBで使えると思うのですが…。

それはそうと、Entity FrameworkではLinq to Entitiesがよく取り上げられますが、それだけではなく[Entity SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/entity-sql-language)と呼ばれるSQL標準とは異なる独自のSQL言語を持っています。基本的にEntity SQLは基本的にはSQL標準に近いため

```
 select max(column1),max(column2),max(column3) from table1;
```

はそのまま実行できるはずです。実行するためには[`ObjectContext.CreateQuery()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.createquery?view=netframework-4.7.2)メソッドを使います。

---

> ```
> db.table1.GroupBy(a => a.Id * 0).Select(a => new {
>   column1 = a.Max(b => b.column1),
>   column2 = a.Max(b => b.column2),
>   column3 = a.Max(b => b.column3),
> }).FirstOrDefault();
> ```

はもう少し簡潔に書けます。`GroupBy()`メソッドにはいくつかオーバーロードがあり、

```
db.table1.GroupBy(a => 0, (_, a) => new {
  column1 = a.Max(b => b.column1),
  column2 = a.Max(b => b.column2),
  column3 = a.Max(b => b.column3),
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

とかできるかもしれません。

（どちらも試していませんので、間違っているかもしれません…。あしからず）

Comment: ”Entity SQL”についてご教示ありがとうございます。GoupByのオーバーロードも含めて、実験結果のご報告ができればと思います。（今日は無理かもしれませんが…）（こういったコメントを残すべきかもよくわかりませんが…）

Comment: どちらも試してみたところ、期待通りの結果が得られましたのでご報告いたします。なお、「GroupBy(a => 0…」については、「GroupBy(a => 1...」のように0は指定できないとのことでした。